# Restrict docker container

Tags: docker

I am new to docker.

We have a requirement to host our app in client's environment.

So, I have to restrict the shell access and no one should be able to extract the code. I have tried to restrict shell access by removing bash access in it, but I am still able to copy the content in the container to server using `docker cp` command.

Basically my container should be running and it should be locked , no one should be able to access the code inside it.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Basically my container should be running and it should be locked , no one should be able to access the code inside it.

You can't make docker images uncopyable. Plain and simple.

It's simply impossible, due to basic facts of computing - and the design of Docker. If you want a computer to execute something, it ***has*** to read it. You can't change that anymore than you can make water less wet.

Furthermore, creators of docker *intended* building upon others work - docker images consists of layers, with layers extending what's beneath. It's designed so that it should be easy to read and add onto.

If you want your code to remain secret, you can't give anyone a copy. It's *that* simple.

Answer (score -2):

Docker containers share the host system's kernel but provide isolated environments for applications to run. Each container contains its own filesystem, processes, network interfaces, and resource allocations, but they all share the same kernel.

Here a few tips to lock/isolate you container

So you need to deploy an host which is hardened and where access is restricted to. Besides that you need to create a docker network for the container that is isolated

```
docker network create --internal isolated_network
```

Only use this network for this one container, otherwise it can also communicate with other containers, if you use it for more containers.

To start with you can use a minimal base image like Alpine Linux, with some iptables rules in the container which deny incoming and outgoing traffic. (but then the container also can't update it's packages and so on)

Comment: Isolating a container won't make the content inaccessible to a sysadmin on the host.

Comment: Yes true that's why also mentioned to harden/restrict the host

Comment: He's trying to secure code against owner of host...