# Monitoring the actions performed to my docker container

Tags: ubuntu, docker, docker-compose

Is there any way to monitor the operations performed on my docker container?

So, i have a docker container with name web. Now i want to check if anyone performs docker exec , docker cp etc , i want to store out that action with the user performed in server and get notified.

NOTE: Docker is installed in ubuntu 22.04 server.

Comment: `auditd` with appropriate rules should help.

Comment: This is probably a follow up of [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/1153350/restrict-docker-container). The answer is still the same: Forget it. Docker images is stored as tarballs in `/var/lib/docker`. You can poke around at the contant without ever invoking a single `docker` command. If you let someone run a docker container on their machine, you can't do *anything* to stop them looking at the content.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Restrict docker container](https://serverfault.com/questions/1153350/restrict-docker-container)

Comment: This is where we learn how many orgs don't audit containers or container related activity. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/752534/linuxkit-auditd-example

Answer (score -2):

Install auditd. Add `-w /usr/bin/dockerd -k docker` to the `/etc/audit/rules.d/audit.rules` file. Then restart the audit daemon using command service auditd restart.

https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-quickly-run-a-basic-security-audit-against-docker-secure-the-host-5e8bd907c12f

Comment: This `auditd` rule monitors `dockerd` binary. It doesn't monitor the docker socket and commands sent to the docker daemon.